# How to update multiple fields in two tables using inner join

Tags: postgresql

I've two tables. And I need two fields to update.
they are connected to each other with a foreign key. I would like to update the fields found in these two tables by using my inner join.

```
UPDATE cert
    SET cert.status = 1, doc.status = 1
    FROM certificates cert 
INNER JOIN documents doc ON doc.data_id = cert.certificate_id
    WHERE cert.status = 0 AND cert.user_id = _expert_id AND doc.data_type = 'CERTIFICATE';
```

The code I mentioned above allows me to update the status field in the certificates table only. In addition, I would like to update the field in the documents table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=91715c3b09a4248e8448493aa7e4c4e8)

```
WITH cert_update AS (
    UPDATE certificates cert
    SET status = 1
    FROM documents doc
    WHERE doc.data_id = cert.certificate_id 
        AND cert.status = 0 
        AND cert.user_id = '2' -- your "_expert_id"
        AND doc.data_type = 'CERTIFICATE'
    RETURNING certificate_id
)
UPDATE documents doc
SET status = 1
FROM cert_update cert
WHERE doc.data_id = cert.certificate_id 
    AND doc.data_type = 'CERTIFICATE';
```

Using the `WITH` clause (*CTE*) you are able to do several updates in one query. The first one gives back the updated `certificate_id` which can be used in the second query.